# SSL Certificate on CNAME

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, cname-record

I have been reviewing the other posts regarding the issue, but having some trouble understanding since I've tried implementing it but still not able to figure it out.

I have 2 servers.

The main server hosts domain `server1.com`

The 2nd server hosts domain `server2.com`

I setup a CNAME for `sub.server1.com` => `sub.server2.com`

When I go to `https://sub.server2.com` it works because I set-up an SSL certificate on `server2.com` (even though it is only a self-signed certificate).

But I can't set-up a certificate for `sub.server1.com` because it's not hosted on `server1.com`, it is a CNAME to `server2.com`.  Well I installed an SSL certificate on Server2. However, when I go to `https://sub.server1.com` I get a `Not Found` error, whereas `https://sub.server2.com` works fine.

First question, did I set the SSL certificate on the correct server for the CNAME?

Second, How come it works directly using SSL (`https://sub.server2.com`), but not found when I try through a CNAME (`https://sub.server1.com`)?

Third, How do I get it the SSL to work on the CNAME (`https://sub.server1.com`)?

Comment: Can you clarify what certificates you have and which names they are valid for? It sounds like you may have no certificate that is valid for `sub.server1.com`...?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist It's a self-signed cert in IIS on `server2`, which is independent from server1 completely and issued by the server only (not trusted source) (doing this for testing before I purchase a trusted SSL cert)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSL certificates are assigned to a hostname/domain name, not a particular machine, and CNAME records are no different in this respect from A records. In your case, the certificate for sub.server1.com must be installed on the Server2 machine since it will be answering requests for that name.

Assuming that the "not found" error is a 404, you may want to verify that sub.server1.com is working on Server2 without SSL (http://sub.server1.com). Once that is verified, duplicate the process and configuration you used to set up SSL for sub.server2.com on the sub.server1.com domain (with a new certificate issued to sub.server1.com).